# The network path was not found exception when running multiple LINQ queries in parallel

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, parallel.foreach, polly

I'm using Entity Framework with .NET 5. My LINQ queries are inside repository and for each query I create and dispose new DBContext. It looks something like these:

```
class MyRepository
{
    public List<entity> Query1(int x)
    {
        //connect to SQL Server to get data
        using(var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            return context.SomeTable1.Where(s => s.Prop == x).ToList();
        }
    }
    
    public List<entity> Query2(string y)
    {
        //connect to SQL Server to get data
        using(var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            return context.SomeTable2.Where(s => s.Prop2 == y).ToList();
        }
    }
}

class Calculator
{
    MyRepository _repo;
    public Calculator(MyRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void Calculate(CalcParam calcParam)
    {
        //one of these LINQ queries can throw exception from time to time when run in parallel. 
        //It works fine when run in sequence
        var r1 = _repo.Query1(calcParam.x);
        var r2 = _repo.Query2(calcParam.y);

        var results = InMemeoryColculation(r1, r2);
        calcParam.AddResults(results);
    }

}
```

I have to perform that queries hundreds of time to solve my problem.

When calculations are performed in sequence everything works great. I'm starting to get that issue when I start increasing number of concurrent calls.

But queries are independent so I can run them in parallel like that:

```
//template action
Action<CalcParam> myAction = ((calcParam) =>
{
    //Calculator will use MyRepository multiple times 
    var calculator = new Calculator(new MyRepository());
    calculator.Calculate(calcParam); 
}

//run in parallel
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };
Parallel.ForEach(allCalcParams, options, (calcParam, state, index) =>
{
    myAction(calcParam);
}
```

Or when using Polly, inside Parallel.ForEach

```
Policy.Handle<Exception>()
.WaitAndRetry(WaitAndRetryArray, (exception, timeSpan, context) =>
{
    Log.Exception(exception);      
})
.Execute(() => myAction(calcParam));
```

where WaitAndRetryArray is

```
private readonly TimeSpan[] WaitAndRetryArray = new[]
{
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16)
};
```

The problem is that I'm frequently getting:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found

exception on a random basis.

App Server and DB Server are on different machines but they live in the same basement in dedicated network. Also, during the calculation App Server and DB Server are using like 20% of their capabilities (nothing else is running there).
Queries are not heavy as well, longest one takes 6 seconds to complete (DB Server CPU utilization never goes beyond 20%).

To mitigate that problem I'm using Polly and retry failing calculations but I can never go beyond the 20% utilization and DegreeOfParallelism = 4.

Could that problem be solely attributed to network issues?
Or maybe I should be running multiple queries using different approach than just looping over in `Parallel.ForEach`? Could it be that it opens connections and keeps them alive after DBContext is disposed?
It feels like current solution is tripping over its own feet when I try to scale it up.
When calculations are performed in sequence

Thank you for help!

Comment: Do you experience the same problem without Polly but running in parallel?

Comment: Yes I do, that is why I started to use Polly. I was thinking that I'll be able to mitigate that problem by just retrying queries from time to time but if I increase MaxDegreeOfParallelism beyond 4 that problem grows. For MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 it works fine, I don't need Polly then

Comment: It might happen that your outgoing connection is limited. For example in case of [Windows XP it was 10](https://superuser.com/questions/309271/does-windows-xp-only-allow-10-inbound-tcp-ip-connections-at-any-one-time). Can you make sure please that you are not reaching that limit?

Comment: @PeterCsala I'm running on Windows Server 2019 Standard. It looks like TcpNumConnections in registry is not set so I assume that there is no limit. But I'll try to verify that somehow. Thank you for a suggestion!

Comment: BTW Parallel.XYZ were designed for CPU insensitive operations. So issuing a database query (which is I/O bound) inside a Parallel loop is not really a good idea. It might make more sense to take advantage of the async operation support of EF. With that you could reach higher troughput.

Comment: The `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in this case means that you can run at most 4 CPU threads at the same time. Most probably 2 physical core with HT >> 4 cores or 4 physical cores.

Comment: App server have 16 cores with HT and DB Server is 8 cores with HT. I can only make them work up to ~20% of CPU utilization. You might be correct that I should try with async calls and Parallel.XYZ is a solution for in memory calculations only.

Comment: Do you need further help?

Comment: I'll try to rewrite the queries to be async and test it then. It will take some time but I think that might be a solution. I'll update you when I'm done!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did you have the chance to rewrite your code?